# Symlink not created by postinst of *.deb package. New file created instead

Tags: bash, package, debian, post-install

I have created a *.deb package which saves some files into the required locations which works fine. During the postinst I generate a new file (merging 2 files together using my own script "mergeconfig"), the file is created fine.

However, on the next line of the postinst, I try to create a symlink to this new file, this doesn't work as expected.

Instead of getting a link, I seem to get a hard copy/a new file:

```
$ ls -la /etc/app/conf-enabled/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2600 Dec  1 17:00 enabledconfig
```

I tried pulling the code out into it's own file and executing it from the postinst file (after giving it executable privileges) and got the same result. Though if I manually run the file I get a valid symlink created:

```
$ /../../updateEnabledConf
 -- Merge this package's server config into app config
Complete
 -- Update conf-enabled symlink

$ ls -la /etc/app/conf-enabled/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   42 Dec  1 17:06 enabledconfig -> /etc/app/conf-available/server-app
```

The code in updateEnableConf is:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVERNAME="server"

APPNAME="app"
CONFIGNAME="enabledconfig"
ETCAPPDIR="/etc/app"
CONFAVAILABLEDIR="$ETCAPPDIR/conf-available"
CONFENABLEDDIR="$ETCAPPDIR/conf-enabled"
CONFAPPDIR="$ETCAPPDIR/conf-app"
CONFSERVERDIR="$ETCAPPDIR/conf-server"

echo " -- Merge this package's server config into app config"
sudo mergeconfig $CONFAPPDIR/$APPNAME $CONFSERVERDIR/$SERVERNAME $CONFAVAILABLEDIR/$SERVERNAME-$APPMNAME

echo " -- Update conf-enabled symlink"
sudo ln -s -f $CONFAVAILABLEDIR/$SERVERNAME-$APPNAME $CONFENABLEDDIR/$CONFIGNAME

exit 0
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, in that the symlink isn't being created correctly during the install of the deb package, but does when I run the same file manually from putty. Both users have sudo access, I'm using gdebi to install the package and I have other packages that create symlinks in the same way without a problem.
Any help would be great

**UPDATE**

After more investigating, turns out the symlinks were being created correctly by the postinst scripts, but there was another file being called directly after with a `sed` command to the path of the symlink:

```
ENABLEDCONF="/etc/app/conf-enabled/enabledconfig"
sed -i 's#<search>#<replace>#g' $ENABLEDCONF
```

This seems to take the data form the file the symlink points too, but overwrites the symlink with the new file. I have updated the sed line to use a readlink command, this has fixed the problem:

```
sed -i 's#<search>#<replace>#g' $(readlink $ENABLEDCONF)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What happens if you `set -x` and run it? You can set it back by `set +x`

Comment: Hey @jmunsch, not seen set -x and set +x before, a quick google seems to be debugging flags? Am I right in thinking you mean to add it like:  

`echo " -- Update conf-enabled symlink"`  
`set -x`  
`sudo ln -s -f $CONFAVAILABLEDIR/$SERVERNAME-$APPNAME $CONFENABLEDDIR/$CONFIGNAME`  
`set +x`  
`exit 0`

Comment: Why are you using sudo? postinst (et al) already run as root.

Comment: @MartynGough you can write the solution also as an answer, not only as update to the question itself...

Answer (score 0):

After more investigating, turns out the symlinks were being created correctly by the postinst scripts, but there was another file being called directly after with a `sed` command to the path of the symlink:

```
ENABLEDCONF="/etc/app/conf-enabled/enabledconfig"
sed -i 's#<search>#<replace>#g' $ENABLEDCONF
```

This seems to take the data form the file the symlink points too, but overwrites the symlink with the new file. I have updated the sed line to use a readlink command, this has fixed the problem:

```
sed -i 's#<search>#<replace>#g' $(readlink $ENABLEDCONF)
```

– Martyn Gough